# Mezclar objetos con mismo id

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy practicando mi logica y mi duda es la siguiente, la consigna me pide dos condiciones primero que se eliminen los id's repetidos y que después se mezclen los valores con id's repetidos en un objeto, hasta ahora esto es lo que voy haciendo:

```js
mylist = [
    {id: 2, name: 'John Doe'},
    {id: 1,name: 'Jane Doe'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Samuel Soe', phone:'+1999999'},
    {id: 2, name: 'John Doe'},
    {id: 4, name: 'John Doe'}
    ];



    function dedupe(list) {
      const arrayFilter = list.reduce((acc, current) => {
          const x = acc.find(item => item.id === current.id);
          if(!x){
              return acc.concat([current]);
          }else{
              return acc
          }
      }, [])
      return arrayFilter
    }

console.log(dedupe(mylist));
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es tu duda/problema?

Comment: la parte de mezclar los valores con id repetidos en un solo objeto

Comment: Ni la lista estaba bien armada ni el ejemplo mostraba el resultado. Revisa que la edición sí corresponda a lo que tienes, por favor.

Comment: `function removeDuplicado(array:any, key :any) {
     return array.filter((obj:any, index:any, self:any) =>
        index === self.findIndex((el:any) => 
            el[key] === obj[key]
        )
    )
}
console.log(removeDuplicado(arry, 'id'))
para solo mostrar los que son duplicados index != self.findIndex(....
`

Answer (score 3):

Si aceptamos que dos objetos con el mismo id deben tener los mismos valores en cualquier propiedad que esté presente (dicho de otro modo, no va a haber casos donde dos elementos con el mismo id tienen distinto nombre, por ejemplo), puedes usar `Object.assign(target, source)` para "mezclarlos":

```js
const list = [
  {id: 2, name: 'John Doe'},
  {id: 1,name: 'Jane Doe'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Samuel Soe', phone:'+1999999'},
  {id: 2, name: 'John Doe', phone:'+1994444'},
  {id: 4, name: 'John Doe'},
  {id: 2, name: 'John Doe', age : 25}
];



function dedupe(list) {
  const arrayFilter = list.reduce((acc, current) => {
    const x = acc.find(item => item.id === current.id);
    if (!x) {
      acc.push(current); //añadiendo un elemento al array
    } else {
      Object.assign(x,current); //mezclando los dos elementos con el mismo id
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return arrayFilter
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(dedupe(list),null,2));
```